# Installing Hamachi on OpenSUSE 11.1 - Where do I get strip?

Tags: opensuse, hamachi

I tried to install Hamachi this morning.  However, when running "make install", I got the error:
"install: cannot run strip: No such file or directory"
Where do I get the strip binary?  It's not in any of the repositories I have on my system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be part of the GNU binutils package.

Answer (score 1):

Having a look at the rpm contents on rpm.pbone.net, strip is part of binutils as stated by TCampbell but you might need libc6 or libc6-dev installed also

pbone is a nice site for finding rpm's, it can be found [here](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/11094432/com/binutils-2.19-9.3.i586.rpm.html)

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

A good way of finding out required dependencies is `zypper`. For instance

```
$ zypper what-provides /usr/bin/strip
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
S | Name     | Type    | Version  | Arch | Repository       
--+----------+---------+----------+------+------------------
i | binutils | package | 2.19-9.3 | i586 | openSUSE-11.1-Oss
```

Admittedly you needed to know that it's `/usr/bin/strip` and not `strip`, but that can be guessed.